# SingletonCluster Actor not getting intialized properly (Unable to send messages / register with receptionist)

Tags: java, java-8, akka, akka-cluster

problem:

I'm creating a cluster singleton actor, but

1. the actor doesn't seem to be getting created ?
2. when i try to register it with the receptionist, it doesn't get
   registered.
3. when i try to send a message to it - it doesn't get
   sent (meaning, when i do a .tell(msg) on this actor, the handling behavior does not get triggered)

Here is what my actor class looks like

```java
public class QueryExecutorActor extends AbstractBehavior<QueryExecutorActor.Command> {
    public static ServiceKey<Command> key = ServiceKey.create(Command.class, "QueryExecutor"); 

private final Config config;
private QueryExecutorActor(ActorContext<Command> context, Config config) {
  super(context);
  this.config = config;
  context.getSystem().receptionist().tell(Receptionist.register(key, context.getSelf()));
  log.info("created")
}

public static Behavior<Command> create(Config config) {
  return Behaviors.setup(context -> new QueryExecutorActor(context, config));
}
```

As you can see, I am telling the receptionist to register this actor, and also printing a log statement - neither of which takes place when the `create()` function is called.

```java
ClusterSingleton singleton = ClusterSingleton.get(system)

ActorRef<QueryExecutor.Command> queryExecutorRef = singleton.init(SingletonActor.of(QueryExecutor.create(config), QueryExecutor.key.id())); 
log.info("Started on", queryExecutorRef.path()); // prints akka://app/system/singletonProxyQueryExecutor-no-dc
```

Here, it "looks" like the actor is created, since i am able to get its path - but how come none of that stuff in the constructor gets ever logged or register itself with the receptionist ?

Comment: I'm curious why you're registering a cluster singleton with a receptionist, as every node in the cluster can more reliably discover the actor via cluster singleton.

Comment: Are you running this on a multi-node cluster, and if so are you checking the logs on other nodes?

Comment: Good point, I don't see a "need" for it to be registered with the receptionist either. But I am just trying to verify some behavior, because it should be able to register itself regardless right?  The reason I am trying to do this is because the code never breaks in the constructor of the actor, so I am not sure if the actor is actually created or not... if it registers with the receptionist, I can atleast see it in the DEBUG logs. Any .tell() to this cluster singleton is failing, the handler for that message never gets triggered.

This is only being run on one node at the moment.

Comment: @PyWalker2797 the creation of the actor will be deferred until the cluster forms successfully. It might be that this isn't happening. How are you configuring and starting the cluster?

Comment: @TimMoore Hi, that was the issue. The cluster did not have any seed nodes joined. I joined the cluster to itself, and the singleton was recognized. I am happy to accept your answer if you post your suggestion as an answer below.